# How can I make Vertical Section Contour plot in Python Plotly

Tags: python, data-visualization, plotly-python

Assuming I have a data for different levels and I want to plot it as different vertical sections of a contour plot.

[image]

I may also need to do it with different datasets, for instance, plotting a volume plot and below it, its gradient, or the error, as a vertical section of a contour plot with a different colormap.

[image]

How can I do it using the Python package for Plotly?
I couldn't find this type of plot in their examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kind of found a way to do it, but it works like a `pcolor` instead of `contour`.
To do that, I have to plot a surface with fixed depth and use the attribute `surfacecolor` to define the color array.

```
fig = go.Figure(data=[
    go.Surface(
        x=x,
        y=y,
        z=z1,
        colorbar=dict(len=0.3, x=0.8, y=0.75),
    ),
    go.Surface(
        x=x,
        y=y,
        z=z2*0-np.pi,
        surfacecolor=z2,
        opacity=0.5,
        cmin=-1,
        cmax=1,
        colorscale='RdBu',
        colorbar=dict(len=0.3, x=0.8, y=0.5),
    ),
    go.Surface(
        x=x,
        y=z2*0+2*np.pi,
        z=y-np.pi,
        surfacecolor=z2,
        opacity=0.5,
        cmin=-1,
        cmax=1,
        colorscale='Spectral',
        colorbar=dict(len=0.3, x=0.8, y=0.25),
    ),
])


fig.show()
```

[image]